# Range of predicted values too narrow

Tags: regression, neural-networks

I have run a neural net model and the plot for acutals vs. predicted was as follows:

[image: Actuals vs. Predicted]

The residuals plot looks weird as well:
[image: Residuals]

I was wondering why my predicted values were confined to a narrow range (4.75-7) instead of ranging from 2-9 as in actuals.

Comment: Could you explain what is "weird" looking about the plots?

Comment: The residuals are okay but the range of predicted values is too narrow as in predicted values (in 1st graph) just vary from (4.75-7) while actual values vary from 2-9.

Comment: But that's completely ordinary!

Comment: Is it?

I am sorry, I am new to this. The R-Square was coming out to be around 0.1 which bothered me. Maybe thats the way data is.

Comment: Yes: one can estimate $R^2$ from the shrinkage of ranges: $(7-4.75)^2/(9-2)^2\approx 0.10.$ Thus, if you told any of us you had a predictive model with an $R^2$ around $0.1$ we could have inverted this calculation and anticipated that the spread of the predictions (measured as standard deviations) would be only about $1/\sqrt{0.1}\approx 1/3$ as great as the spread of actual values.  That what $R^2$ *means*. So: you have a good question, but there's nothing strange going on!

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. 

A follow up would be, what would be the underlying cause of this (bad model, any particular flaw in data) or just that data is like that.

And secondly, is there anything that can be done to improve this fit then like transformation.

Comment: All those are legitimate possibilities.  There is a concept of *irreducible error:* no matter how much data you collect, there will be variation you simply cannot account for, no matter what the model.  The cause is usually some combination of lack of model fit and irreducible error.  How to assess this and what to do about it depends on the circumstances: there's no general answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad because there is no general answer to this question & the core of OP's misunderstanding has  been answered in comments.

Comment: If the core [of the question] has been answered in comments, perhaps the  comments could be converted into an answer